# Insert empty value from datagridview

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datagridview

I am trying to insert empty value from datagridview when the cell is left empty. This is what I'm doing:

```
using (var context = new EmployeeEntities())
{
  EMPLOYEE emp= new EMPLOYEE ();
  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvLoadTable.Rows)
  {
   if (row.Cells[0].Value != null)
   {
     emp.EMP_ID = int.Parse(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
     emp.DEPARTMENT = row.Cells[2].Value is DBNull ? string.Empty : row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
     //Also tried: emp.DEPARTMENT = row.Cells[2].Value is DBNull ? DBNull.Value.ToString() : row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
     context.EMPLOYEE.AddObject(emp);
     context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
 }
```

But it's not working, when I try to insert null value it throws the "Object reference is not set to an instance of an object" exception. What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: While I could point where problem is I wont do that, why? Because this is typical error and you should learn how to handle it. Add breakpoint on line where you getting exception and inspect variables and they types....one of them is null and not DBNull. Also note `null`, `DBNull` and `DBNull.Value` are different things.

Comment: You can add an answer for your question and accept it. ;)